# HTML custom input image tags?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, web-applications

[Hand Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or0Bk.gif)

Hi guys!
I'm making a small web application in angular. I want to know if it is possible to place tags on an image and allow for a user input when the tag is clicked?

Eg. In the above image, I want to place tags at each circled number. When the number is clicked.. and input box should pop up and allow for a user to enter a description.

How do i go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey dude. Yes it is possible. But putting tags on each circle will be little tricky. You can achieve it using image mapping refer this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp You can trigger a modal using click events in angular

Comment: I think you need to be more specific on your question, Like which version of angular and any code snippets you tried etc.

Comment: I was looking at tag mapping, but how do i trigger an input field from clicking the tag instead of loading a new page?
I'm using Angular2/4. I haven't tried any code snippets yet.. I'm looking for a way to start or a method to try because i don't know where to begin

Comment: In each tag area you can initiate click event and trigger a function. In that function, you can initiate a input box in a modal. Function can be written in typescript.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this using Rakesh Rajan's comment.

Used mapping reference for the image and added an onclick function to initiate an input box.

Thanks!